# Display specific data in a td with multiple Arrays using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have an array with key and value after applying d3.js into my code and when the result come out it has **key** and **value** pair. So I assign each team to **key** and the cost for **value**. It'll look like this in the console log

**Console.log for key and value**

```
Rate for current month [{"key":"Sample 1","value":6400},{"key":"Sample 2","value":3200}]
Rate for next month [{"key":"Sample 1","value":7360},{"key":"Sample 2","value":3680}]
Rate for 2nd next Month [{"key":"Sample 1","value":7040},{"key":"Sample 2","value":3520}]
```

- So my problems is I have to use 3 different arrays for the ngFor to display those values. And I want those values to be put in the right place. Here's the code and the table display on the browser.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team Name</th>
      <th>Current Month Rate ({{getCurrentMonth()}}) </th>
      <th>Next Month Rate ({{getNextMonth()}})</th>
      <th>2nd Next Month Rate ({{get2ndNextMonth()}})</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr *ngFor="let rc of rateCurrentMonth">
      <th  scope="row" >{{ rc.key }}</th>
      <td >{{rc.value | currency }}</td>
      <td *ngFor = "let nm of rateNextMonth">{{nm.value  | currency }}</td>
      <td *ngFor = "let nn of rate2ndNextMonth">{{ nn.value  | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Total</th>
      <td>{{ getCurrentMonthTotal() | currency }}</td>
      <td>{{ getNextMonthTotal()  | currency }}</td>
      <td>{{ get2ndNextMonthTotal()  | currency }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<hr />
```

**Table Display**
[image: Table Display]

- Here's the TS file

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../../services/user.service';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {User} from '../../models/user.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ratecost',
  templateUrl: './ratecost.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ratecost.component.css']
})
export class RatecostComponent implements OnInit {
  rateNextMonth = [];
  rate2ndNextMonth = [];
  rateCurrentMonth = [];

    sumCurrentMonth = 0;
    sumYear = 0


   months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  d = new Date();

  thirtyOne = [0,2,4,6,7,9,11]
  thirty = [3,5,8,10]
  feb = [1];


  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchCurrentMonth();
    this.fetchNextMonth();
    this.fetch2ndNextMonth()
  }
// get the Key and Value for the current Month
// rateCurrentMonth
// OutPut: {key: "Sample 1", value: 6400} {key: "Sample2", value: 3200}
 private  fetchCurrentMonth() {
    this.userService
      .getUsers(0,0)
      .subscribe(data => {
        const rateCurrentMonth = d3.nest<User, number>()
          .key((user: User) => user.team)
          .rollup((users: User[]) => {
            return d3.sum(users, (u: User) => {
              if(u.hourlyRate &&  ( this.thirty.indexOf(this.d.getMonth()) === 1)){
               return (u.hourlyRate * 8 * 22)
              }
               if (u.hourlyRate && (this.thirtyOne.indexOf(this.d.getMonth()) === 1)){
                return (u.hourlyRate * 8 * 23)
              }  if (u.annualRate){
              return u.annualRate / 12
            }
              return u.hourlyRate * 8 * 20
            });
          })
          .entries(data.users);
        this.rateCurrentMonth = rateCurrentMonth;
        console.log('rate for current month', rateCurrentMonth)
      });
  }


// get the Key and Value for the next Month
// rateNextMonth[]
// OutPut: {key: "Sample 1", value: 7360} {key: "Sample2", value: 3680}
   private  fetchNextMonth() {
    this.userService
      .getUsers(0,0)
      .subscribe(data => {
        const rateNextMonth = d3.nest<User, number>()
          .key((user: User) => user.team)
          .rollup((users: User[]) => {
            return d3.sum(users, (u: User) => {
              if(u.hourlyRate &&  ( this.thirty.indexOf(this.d.getMonth() + 1) === 1)){
               return (u.hourlyRate * 8 * 22)
              }
               if (u.hourlyRate && (this.thirtyOne.indexOf(this.d.getMonth() + 1) === 1)){
                return (u.hourlyRate * 8 * 23)
              }  if (u.annualRate){
              return u.annualRate / 12
            }
              return u.hourlyRate * 8 * 20
            });
          })
          .entries(data.users);
        this.rateNextMonth = rateNextMonth
        console.log('rate for next month',rateNextMonth)
      });
  }

 // get the Key and Value for the 2nd next Month
//  array is rate2ndNextMonth = []
// OutPut: {key: "Sample 1", value: 7040} {key: "Sample2", value: 3520}
 private fetch2ndNextMonth() {
    this.userService
      .getUsers(0,0)
      .subscribe(data => {
        const rate2ndNextMonth = d3.nest<User, number>()
          .key((user: User) => user.team)
          .rollup((users: User[]) => {
            return d3.sum(users, (u: User) => {
              if(u.hourlyRate &&  (this.getThirtyIndex() + 2) === 1){
               return (u.hourlyRate * 8 * 22)
              }
              else if (u.hourlyRate && (this.getThirtyOneIndex() + 2) === 1){
                return (u.hourlyRate * 8 * 23)
              } else if (u.annualRate){
              return u.annualRate / 12
            }
              return u.hourlyRate * 8 * 20
            });
          })
          .entries(data.users);
        this.rate2ndNextMonth = rate2ndNextMonth;
        console.log('Rate for 2nd next Month', rate2ndNextMonth)
      });
  }

//   get the total of current Month
getCurrentMonthTotal() {
  return this.rateCurrentMonth.map(t => t.value)
  .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)
}

// get the total of Next Month
getNextMonthTotal() {
    return this.rateNextMonth.map(t => t.value)
    .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)
  }

//   get the total of 2nd Next Month
  get2ndNextMonthTotal() {
    return this.rate2ndNextMonth.map(t => t.value)
    .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)
  }

// display current month on table
getCurrentMonth(m){
  m = this.months[this.d.getMonth()];
  return m;
}

// display next month on table
getNextMonth(n){
  n = this.months[(this.d.getMonth() + 1)];
  return n;
}

// display 2nd next month on table
get2ndNextMonth(nn){
  nn = this.months[(this.d.getMonth() + 2)];
  return nn;
}


getThirtyIndex(){
  return this.thirty.indexOf(this.d.getMonth()) 
}


getThirtyOneIndex(){
  return this.thirtyOne.indexOf(this.d.getMonth())
}
}
```

- So the 1st column of *Current Month* display correctly since i use the **key value** for the same array but the other 2 doesn't display like wanted. I'd much appreciate the help.

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable))` if possible instead of giving us a picture of your console. Much easier to read and search for.

Comment: will do Heretic

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are exactly trying to show in the table but if the link to table display is what you want as out put, what you are doing is wrong in the inner for loops.

```html
<td *ngFor = "let nm of rateNextMonth">{{nm.value  | currency }}</td>
 <td *ngFor = "let nn of rate2ndNextMonth">{{ nn.value  | currency}}</td>
```

will generate **all** next month's and second month's values in each row.
what you are possibly looking for is somthing like:

```html
<td>{{ findRate2ndNextMonthRateByKey(rc.key) | currency}}</td>
```

which "*findRate2ndNextMonthRateByKey*"  will be a function that finds the corresponding value for given key.

Comment: hi Thirller, thanks for the responding. I just want to be a little bit clarified that each **key** is a team name which you can see on the left hand-side of  the table _Sample 1_ _Sample 2_ and each of those teams will have **value** that display to the cost of the 3 months.

Comment: I made a quick demo for you so you have an idea how to do it. The only thing that I suggest you is that to make a variable keeping all the team names inside and use that to loop through. In the example it is called allTeams. you can reach this using set data structures to be sure you don't have duplicates. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvhtlu

Comment: @KhangNguyen it is worthy to mention that depending on the use case of your project you might need to restructure your data from arrays of map to map of maps. something like => { "firstMotnh":{"firstTeam":5222, "secondTeam":45451, ...}, "secondMonth":{ "firstTeam":5222, "secondTeam":45451, ..},...} this will make things a lot easier.

Comment: I just updated the post, will be more clarified for you. Thanks again Thriller

Comment: @KhangNguyen I have no clue about this d3.js structure. to me it seems like a huge effort to do something simple. as I don't know how to efficiently extract the d3 data and convert it to the data structure that I gave you before, Even though I don't like the dirty solution but I modified the code to comply to this weird data structure. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvhtlu